# Bug usando :hover e click no chrome

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome

Estou corrigindo um problema que consegui simular apenas no chrome. Após clicar diversas vezes nos itens ancora o menu fecha, sem motivo algum. Segue o código: (não consegui colar formatado pois ultrapassa o limite de caracteres da pergunta)

```html
<html>
   <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
   </head>
   <body>
      <aside class="aside">
         <div class="nav-primary nav-toggle d-none d-md-inline"> <span class="item-text"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i> </span> </div>
         <nav id="" class="sidebar">
            <ul id="menu-itens" class="nav">
               <li>
                  <a href="javascript: void(0);" data-toggle="collapse-next" class="has-submenu"> <em class="fal fa-address-card"></em><span class="item-text">item</span> </a> 
                  <ul class="nav collapse" aria-expanded="false" style="">
                     <li> <a href="javascript: void(0);" data-toggle="collapse-next" class="has-submenu"> <em class="far fa-boxes"></em><span class="item-text">item</span> </a>  </li>
                     <li> <a href="javascript: void(0);" data-toggle="collapse-next" class="has-submenu"> <em class="fas fa-user-tie"></em><span class="item-text">item</span> </a>  </li>
                     <li> <a href="javascript: void(0);" data-toggle="collapse-next" class="has-submenu"> <em class="far fa-university"></em><span class="item-text">item</span> </a>  </li>
                     <li>
                        <a href="javascript: void(0);" data-toggle="collapse-next" class="has-submenu"> <em class="fal fa-money-bill-alt"></em><span class="item-text">item</span> </a> 
                        <ul class="nav collapse" aria-expanded="false" style="">
                           <li> <a href="#" data-toggle="" class="no-submenu"><span class="item-text">item</span> </a></li>
                           <li> <a href="#" data-toggle="" class="no-submenu"> <span class="item-text">item</span></a></li>
                           <li> <a href="#" data-toggle="" class="no-submenu"> <span class="item-text">item</span></a></li>
                           <li> <a href="#" data-toggle="" class="no-submenu"><span class="item-text">item</span> </a></li>
                           <li> <a href="#" data-toggle="" class="no-submenu"> <span class="item-text">item</span> </a></li>
                           <li> <a href="#" data-toggle="" class="no-submenu"><span class="item-text">item</span> </a></li>
                           <li> <a href="#" data-toggle="" class="no-submenu"> <span class="item-text">item</span> </a></li>
                           <li> <a href="#" data-toggle="" class="no-submenu"><span class="item-text">item</span> </a></li>
                           <li> <a href="#" data-toggle="" class="no-submenu"> <span class="item-text">item</span> </a></li>
                        </ul>
                     </li>
                     <li> <a href="javascript: void(0);" data-toggle="collapse-next" class="has-submenu"> <em class="far fa-object-ungroup"></em><span class="item-text">item</span> </a>  </li>
                     <li> <a href="#" data-toggle="" class="no-submenu"><span class="item-text">item</span> </a></li>
                     <li> <a href="#" data-toggle="" class="no-submenu"><span class="item-text">item</span> </a></li>
                     <li> <a href="#" data-toggle="" class="no-submenu"><span class="item-text">item</span> </a></li>
                     <li> <a href="#" data-toggle="" class="no-submenu"><span class="item-text">item</span> </a></li>
                     <li> <a href="#" data-toggle="" class="no-submenu"><span class="item-text">item</span> </a></li>
                     <li> <a href="#" data-toggle="" class="no-submenu"><span class="item-text">item</span> </a></li>
                  </ul>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <a href="javascript: void(0);" data-toggle="collapse-next" class="has-submenu"> <em class="fal fa-handshake"></em><span class="item-text">item</span> </a> 
                  <ul class="nav collapse show" aria-expanded="false" style="">
                     <li> <a href="javascript: void(0);" data-toggle="collapse-next" class="has-submenu"> <em class="far fa-file-alt"></em><span class="item-text">item</span> </a>  </li>
                     <li>
                        <a href="javascript: void(0);" data-toggle="collapse-next" class="has-submenu"> <em class="far fa-truck"></em><span class="item-text">item</span> </a> 
                        <ul class="nav collapse" aria-expanded="false">
                           <li> <a href="#" data-toggle="" class="no-submenu"> <span class="item-text">item</span> </a></li>
                           <li> <a href="#" data-toggle="" class="no-submenu"> <span class="item-text">item</span> </a></li>
                           <li> <a href="#" data-toggle="" class="no-submenu"> <span class="item-text">item</span> </a></li>
                           <li> <a href="#" data-toggle="" class="no-submenu"> <span class="item-text">item</span> </a></li>
                           <li> <a href="#" data-toggle="" class="no-submenu"> <span class="item-text">item</span></a></li>
                           <li> <a href="#" data-toggle="" class="no-submenu"> <span class="item-text">item</span></a></li>
                        </ul>
                     </li>
                     <li> <a href="javascript: void(0);" data-toggle="collapse-next" class="has-submenu"> <em class="far fa-truck-loading"></em><span class="item-text">item</span> </a>  </li>
                     <li> <a href="javascript: void(0);" data-toggle="collapse-next" class="has-submenu"> <em class="far fa-shopping-cart"></em><span class="item-text">item</span> </a>  </li>
                     <li> <a href="javascript: void(0);" data-toggle="collapse-next" class="has-submenu"> <em class="far fa-clipboard-list"></em><span class="item-text">item</span> </a>  </li>
                     <li> <a href="javascript: void(0);" data-toggle="collapse-next" class="has-submenu"> <em class="far fa-wrench"></em><span class="item-text">item</span> </a>  </li>
                     <li> <a href="javascript: void(0);" data-toggle="collapse-next" class="has-submenu"> <em class="far fa-file-alt"></em><span class="item-text">item</span> </a>  </li>
                     <li>
                        <a href="javascript: void(0);" data-toggle="collapse-next" class="has-submenu">
                           <em class="far fa-shopping-basket"></em><span  
                     </li>
                     <li> <a href="javascript: void(0);" data-toggle="collapse-next" class="has-submenu"> <em class="far fa-dollar-sign"></em><span class="item-text">item</span> </a>  </li> 
                     <li> <a href="javascript: void(0);" data-toggle="collapse-next" class="has-submenu"> <em class="far fa-users"></em><span class="item-text">item</span> </a>  </li>
                     <li>
                        <a href="javascript: void(0);" data-toggle="collapse-next" class="has-submenu">
                           <em class="fal fa-dot-circle"></em><span  
                     </li>
                     <li> <a href="javascript: void(0);" data-toggle="collapse-next" class="has-submenu"> <em class="far fa-clipboard-list"></em><span class="item-text">item</span> </a>  </li> 
                     <li> <a href="javascript: void(0);" data-toggle="collapse-next" class="has-submenu"> <em class="fal fa-dot-circle"></em><span class="item-text">item</span> </a>  </li>
                     <li> <a href="javascript: void(0);" data-toggle="collapse-next" class="has-submenu"> <em class="far fa-box-full"></em><span class="item-text">item</span> </a>  </li>
                     <li>
                        <a href="javascript: void(0);" data-toggle="collapse-next" class="has-submenu">
                           <em class="fal fa-dot-circle"></em><span  
                     </li>
                     <li> <a href="#" data-toggle="" class="no-submenu"><span class="item-text">item</span> </a></li> 
                     <li> <a href="#" data-toggle="" class="no-submenu"><span class="item-text">item</span> </a></li>
                     <li> <a href="#" data-toggle="" class="no-submenu"> <span class="item-text">item</span> </a></li>
                  </ul>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <a href="javascript: void(0);" data-toggle="collapse-next" class="has-submenu"> <em class="far fa-cubes"></em><span class="item-text">item</span> </a> 
                  <ul class="nav collapse" aria-expanded="false" style="">
                     <li> <a href="javascript: void(0);" data-toggle="collapse-next" class="has-submenu"> <em class="far fa-clipboard-list"></em><span class="item-text">item</span> </a>  </li>
                     <li> <a href="javascript: void(0);" data-toggle="collapse-next" class="has-submenu"> <em class="fal fa-dot-circle"></em><span class="item-text">item</span> </a>  </li>
                     <li> <a href="javascript: void(0);" data-toggle="collapse-next" class="has-submenu"> <em class="fal fa-dot-circle"></em><span class="item-text">item</span> </a>  </li>
                     <li> <a href="javascript: void(0);" data-toggle="collapse-next" class="has-submenu"> <em class="far fa-industry-alt"></em><span class="item-text">item</span> </a>  </li>
                     <li> <a href="javascript: void(0);" data-toggle="collapse-next" class="has-submenu"> <em class="far fa-industry-alt"></em><span class="item-text">item</span> </a>  </li>
                     <li> <a href="#" data-toggle="" class="no-submenu"><span class="item-text">item</span> </a></li>
                     <li> <a href="#" data-toggle="" class="no-submenu"><span class="item-text">item</span> </a></li>
                     <li> <a href="#" data-toggle="" class="no-submenu"><span class="item-text">item</span> </a></li>
                     <li> <a href="#" data-toggle="" class="no-submenu"><span class="item-text">item</span> </a></li>
                     <li> <a href="#" data-toggle="" class="no-submenu"><span class="item-text">item</span> </a></li>
                  </ul>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <a href="javascript: void(0);" data-toggle="collapse-next" class="has-submenu"> <em class="fal fa-money-bill-alt"></em><span class="item-text">item</span> </a> 
                  <ul class="nav collapse" aria-expanded="false" style="">
                     <li> <a href="javascript: void(0);" data-toggle="collapse-next" class="has-submenu"> <em class="far fa-dollar-sign"></em><span class="item-text">item</span> </a>  </li>
                     <li> <a href="javascript: void(0);" data-toggle="collapse-next" class="has-submenu"> <em class="far fa-money-check-alt"></em><span class="item-text">item</span> </a>  </li>
                     <li> <a href="javascript: void(0);" data-toggle="collapse-next" class="has-submenu"> <em class="far fa-chart-line"></em><span class="item-text">item</span> </a>  </li>
                     <li> <a href="#" data-toggle="" class="no-submenu"><span class="item-text">item</span> </a></li>
                     <li> <a href="#" data-toggle="" class="no-submenu"><span class="item-text">item</span> </a></li>
                     <li> <a href="#" data-toggle="" class="no-submenu"><span class="item-text">item</span> </a></li>
                     <li> <a href="#" data-toggle="" class="no-submenu"><span class="item-text">item</span> </a></li>
                     <li> <a href="#" data-toggle="" class="no-submenu"><span class="item-text">item</span> </a></li>
                     <li> <a href="#" data-toggle="" class="no-submenu"><span class="item-text">item</span> </a></li>
                     <li> <a href="#" data-toggle="" class="no-submenu"><span class="item-text">item</span> </a></li>
                     <li> <a href="#" data-toggle="" class="no-submenu"><span class="item-text">item</span> </a></li>
                  </ul>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <a href="javascript: void(0);" data-toggle="collapse-next" class="has-submenu"> <em class="fal fa-university"></em><span class="item-text">item</span> </a> 
                  <ul class="nav collapse" aria-expanded="false" style="">
                     <li> <a href="javascript: void(0);" data-toggle="collapse-next" class="has-submenu"> <em class="fal fa-dot-circle"></em><span class="item-text">item</span> </a>  </li>
                     <li> <a href="javascript: void(0);" data-toggle="collapse-next" class="has-submenu"> <em class="fal fa-dot-circle"></em><span class="item-text">item</span> </a>  </li>
                     <li> <a href="javascript: void(0);" data-toggle="collapse-next" class="has-submenu"> <em class="fal fa-dot-circle"></em><span class="item-text">item</span> </a>  </li>
                  </ul>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <a href="javascript: void(0);" data-toggle="collapse-next" class="has-submenu"> <em class="far fa-chart-line"></em><span class="item-text">item</span> </a> 
                  <ul class="nav collapse" aria-expanded="false" style="">
                     <li> <a href="javascript: void(0);" data-toggle="collapse-next" class="has-submenu"> <em class="far fa-clipboard-list"></em><span class="item-text">item</span> </a>  </li>
                     <li> <a href="#" data-toggle="" class="no-submenu"><span class="item-text">item</span> </a></li>
                     <li> <a href="#" data-toggle="" class="no-submenu"><span class="item-text">item</span> </a></li>
                     <li> <a href="#" data-toggle="" class="no-submenu"><span class="item-text">item</span> </a></li>
                     <li> <a href="#" data-toggle="" class="no-submenu"><span class="item-text">item</span> </a></li>
                     <li> <a href="#" data-toggle="" class="no-submenu"><span class="item-text">item</span> </a></li>
                     <li> <a href="#" data-toggle="" class="no-submenu"><span class="item-text">item</span> </a></li>
                     <li> <a href="#" data-toggle="" class="no-submenu"><span class="item-text">item</span> </a></li>
                     <li> <a href="#" data-toggle="" class="no-submenu"><span class="item-text">item</span> </a></li>
                     <li> <a href="#" data-toggle="" class="no-submenu"><span class="item-text">item</span> </a></li>
                     <li> <a href="#" data-toggle="" class="no-submenu"><span class="item-text">item</span> </a></li>
                  </ul>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </nav>
      </aside>
<script>
var jDocument = $(document);
var navToggle = $('.nav-toggle');
var sidebarToggle = $('.sidebar-toggle');
var sidebar = $('.sidebar');
var collapseSelector = '[data-toggle="collapse-next"]',
colllapsibles = $('.sidebar .collapse').collapse({ toggle: false }),
toggledClass = 'aside-collapsed',
$body = $('body'),
phone_mq = 768;

function notify(a, b, c) {
   console.log(b)
}

var fixedSidebar = $('.fixed-sidebar');
var fixedMenu = 0;

fixedSidebar.off("click").on('click', function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var date = new Date();
   date.setTime(date.getTime() + (1000 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
   if (fixedMenu == 0) {
      fixedMenu = 1;
      sidebar.addClass('fixo');
      notify("", "Menu fixo!", "success");
   } else {
      fixedMenu = 0;
      sidebar.removeClass('fixo');
      notify("", "Menu dinâmico!", "success");
   }
   SetCookie("fixedMenu", fixedMenu, date);
});

sidebarToggle.off("click").on("click", function () {
   sidebar.toggleClass('toggled');
});

jDocument.on('click.sidebar', collapseSelector, function (e) {
   var $that = $(this);
   setTimeout(function () {
      var $target = $that.siblings('ul');
      var $targetParent = $target.parent().parent();
      if ($targetParent.has("ul").hasClass("show") == true) {
         colllapsibles.not($targetParent).collapse('hide');
      } else {
         colllapsibles.collapse('hide');
      }
      $target.collapse('show');
   }, 1);
});
</script>
      <style> .aside:hover .sidebar { left: 0; }   .aside .sidebar { display: block; left: -255px; transition: left .6s ease; }    .aside { position: absolute; margin-top: 0px; top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; z-index: 1031; }  .aside .nav-primary { width: 30px; position: fixed; background-color: #39a7df; /*#fafafa;*/ color: #ffffff; display: block; height: calc(100% - 29px); border-right: 1px solid #39a7df; z-index: 1; }  .aside .nav-primary>.item-text { color: #ffffff; font-size: 20px; font-weight: 100; display: block; margin: 0px 8px; /*@include rotate(-90,3);*/ }  .aside .nav-primary .item-text i { font-size: 16px; }  .aside .sidebar { position: fixed; top: 0; background-color: #39a7df; height: calc(100% - 29px); overflow-y: auto; border-right: 1px solid #39a7df; -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; width: 250px; z-index: 2; }  .sidebar>.nav { position: relative; margin-top: 5px; }  .sidebar>.nav>.nav-heading:first-child { padding-top: 0px; }    .sidebar .nav-heading:hover { background-color: #39a7df !important; color: #ffffff !important; }  .sidebar .nav-labels { list-style-type: none; padding: 0; margin: 0; }  .sidebar .nav-labels>.nav-labels-item { padding: 5px 25px; font-size: 13px; }  .sidebar .nav-labels>.nav-labels-item>a { color: #ffffff; }  .sidebar .nav-labels>.nav-labels-item .circle { margin-right: 20px; margin-left: 0; }  .sidebar .nav>li { border-left: 2px solid transparent; display: block; width: 100%; }  .sidebar .nav>li>a, .sidebar .nav>li>.nav-item { padding: 12px 5px 12px 10px; color: #ffffff; letter-spacing: .025em; /*font-weight: 600;*/ -webkit-transition: background-color 0.2s ease; -o-transition: background-color 0.2s ease; transition: background-color 0.2s ease; display: block; text-decoration: none; }  .sidebar .nav>li>a:focus, .sidebar .nav>li>.nav-item:focus { color: #fff; background-color: #45AC6C; }  .sidebar .nav>li>a>em, .sidebar .nav>li>.nav-item>em { width: 1.5em; color: #ffffff; }  .sidebar .nav>li.active  /*.sidebar .nav > li.active > a,*/ /*.sidebar .nav > li.active > a > .item-text*/ /*.sidebar .nav > li.active .nav,*/ { background-color: #45AC6C; color: #fff; }  .sidebar .nav>li:hover, .sidebar .nav>li:hover>a, .sidebar .nav>li:hover>a>.item-text .sidebar .nav>li:hover .nav { background-color: #C1332F; color: #fff; }  .sidebar .nav>li.active>a>em, .sidebar .nav>li:hover>a>em { color: #ffffff; }  .sidebar .nav>li.active { border-left-color: #39a7df; }  .sidebar .nav .nav { padding-left: 25px; background-color: #39a7df; }  .sidebar .nav .nav>li { border-left: 0; }  .sidebar .nav .nav>li>a, .sidebar .nav .nav>li>.nav-item { display: block; position: relative; padding: 10px 2px 10px 6px; background-color: transparent !important; font-weight: normal; }  .sidebar .nav .nav>li>a:focus, .sidebar .nav .nav>li>.nav-item:focus, .sidebar .nav .nav>li>a:hover, .sidebar .nav .nav>li>.nav-item:hover { color: #fff; }  .sidebar .nav .nav>li.active>a, .sidebar .nav .nav>li.active>.nav-item { color: #fff; }  .sidebar .nav .nav>li.active>a:after, .sidebar .nav .nav>li.active>.nav-item:after { border-color: #1c75bf; background-color: #1c75bf; } </style>
   </body>
</html>
```

Não consegui simular este problema no Firefox. O problema ocorre após clicar diversas vezes abrindo ou fechando os elementos raiz.

Saberiam me dizer como corrigir esse problema?

Segue a simulação: https://youtu.be/J6pinvC7-Q4

Comment: Não consegui reproduzir o problema aqui - e olha que tentei clicar loucamente pelo menu.

Comment: PS: tem que deixar o mouse parado depois do clique, no vídeo mostra melhor como reproduzir.

Comment: Teste simular seu código no Codepen. Acho que seria relevante. Seu código esta inline, fica complicado de ler e entender a rotina para quem acessa a plataforma, e bate o olho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use o método `.hover()` do jQuery alternando uma classe que determina quando o menu está aberto ou fechado. Ao adicionar a classe com `.hover()` no evento `mouseenter` o menu irá abrir, no evento `mouseleave`, a classe será removida e o menu se fechará. Um outro evento `click` irá alterar o valor de uma variável de controle (`estado`) para evitar que o menu se feche em um pequeno intervalo de tempo determinado pelo `setTimeout`.

O problema é que quando você clica em um item do menu, o aside pode perder o `hover` (evento que chama o `mouseleave`), que é a condição para ele ficar aberto. Controlando pelo jQuery você evita, pelo `mouseleave`, que a classe que mantém o menu aberto seja removida.

Altere os dois primeiros estilos do CSS para:

```
.aside .sidebar.ativo {
   left: 0;
}

.aside .sidebar {
   display: block;
   left: -255px;
   transition: left .6s ease;
}
```

E adicione o código jQuery no script:

```
var estado;

$(".aside").hover(
   function(){
      $(".sidebar", this).addClass("ativo");
   },
   function(){
      if(!estado){
         $(".sidebar", this).removeClass("ativo");
      }
   }
).on("click", function(){
   estado = true;
   setTimeout(function(){
      estado = false;
   }, 50);
});
```

**Funcionamento (execute em tela cheia):**

```js
var jDocument = $(document);
var navToggle = $('.nav-toggle');
var sidebarToggle = $('.sidebar-toggle');
var sidebar = $('.sidebar');
var collapseSelector = '[data-toggle="collapse-next"]',
colllapsibles = $('.sidebar .collapse').collapse({ toggle: false }),
toggledClass = 'aside-collapsed',
$body = $('body'),
phone_mq = 768;

function notify(a, b, c) {
   console.log(b)
}

var fixedSidebar = $('.fixed-sidebar');
var fixedMenu = 0;

fixedSidebar.off("click").on('click', function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var date = new Date();
   date.setTime(date.getTime() + (1000 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
   if (fixedMenu == 0) {
      fixedMenu = 1;
      sidebar.addClass('fixo');
      notify("", "Menu fixo!", "success");
   } else {
      fixedMenu = 0;
      sidebar.removeClass('fixo');
      notify("", "Menu dinâmico!", "success");
   }
   SetCookie("fixedMenu", fixedMenu, date);
});

sidebarToggle.off("click").on("click", function () {
   sidebar.toggleClass('toggled');
});

jDocument.on('click.sidebar', collapseSelector, function (e) {
   var $that = $(this);
   setTimeout(function () {
      var $target = $that.siblings('ul');
      var $targetParent = $target.parent().parent();
      if ($targetParent.has("ul").hasClass("show") == true) {
         colllapsibles.not($targetParent).collapse('hide');
      } else {
         colllapsibles.collapse('hide');
      }
      $target.collapse('show');
   }, 1);
});

var estado;

$(".aside").hover(
   function(){
      $(".sidebar", this).addClass("ativo");
   },
   function(){
      if(!estado){
         $(".sidebar", this).removeClass("ativo");
      }
   }
).on("click", function(){
   estado = true;
   setTimeout(function(){
      estado = false;
   }, 50);
});
```

```css
.aside .sidebar.ativo {
   left: 0;
}

.aside .sidebar {
   display: block;
   left: -255px;
   transition: left .6s ease;
}

.aside { position: absolute; margin-top: 0px; top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; z-index: 1031; }

.aside .nav-primary { width: 30px; position: fixed; background-color: #39a7df; /*#fafafa;*/ color: #ffffff; display: block; height: calc(100% - 29px); border-right: 1px solid #39a7df; z-index: 1; }

.aside .nav-primary>.item-text { color: #ffffff; font-size: 20px; font-weight: 100; display: block; margin: 0px 8px; /*@include rotate(-90,3);*/ }

.aside .nav-primary .item-text i { font-size: 16px; }

.aside .sidebar { position: fixed; top: 0; background-color: #39a7df; height: calc(100% - 29px); overflow-y: auto; border-right: 1px solid #39a7df; -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; width: 250px; z-index: 2; }

.sidebar>.nav { position: relative; margin-top: 5px; }

.sidebar>.nav>.nav-heading:first-child { padding-top: 0px; }

.sidebar .nav-heading:hover { background-color: #39a7df !important; color: #ffffff !important; }

.sidebar .nav-labels { list-style-type: none; padding: 0; margin: 0; }

.sidebar .nav-labels>.nav-labels-item { padding: 5px 25px; font-size: 13px; }

.sidebar .nav-labels>.nav-labels-item>a { color: #ffffff; }

.sidebar .nav-labels>.nav-labels-item .circle { margin-right: 20px; margin-left: 0; }

.sidebar .nav>li { border-left: 2px solid transparent; display: block; width: 100%; }

.sidebar .nav>li>a, .sidebar .nav>li>.nav-item { padding: 12px 5px 12px 10px; color: #ffffff; letter-spacing: .025em; /*font-weight: 600;*/ -webkit-transition: background-color 0.2s ease; -o-transition: background-color 0.2s ease; transition: background-color 0.2s ease; display: block; text-decoration: none; }

.sidebar .nav>li>a:focus, .sidebar .nav>li>.nav-item:focus { color: #fff; background-color: #45AC6C; }

.sidebar .nav>li>a>em, .sidebar .nav>li>.nav-item>em { width: 1.5em; color: #ffffff; }

.sidebar .nav>li.active  /*.sidebar .nav > li.active > a,*/ /*.sidebar .nav > li.active > a > .item-text*/ /*.sidebar .nav > li.active .nav,*/ { background-color: #45AC6C; color: #fff; }

.sidebar .nav>li:hover, .sidebar .nav>li:hover>a, .sidebar .nav>li:hover>a>.item-text .sidebar .nav>li:hover .nav { background-color: #C1332F; color: #fff; }

.sidebar .nav>li.active>a>em, .sidebar .nav>li:hover>a>em { color: #ffffff; }

.sidebar .nav>li.active { border-left-color: #39a7df; }

.sidebar .nav .nav { padding-left: 25px; background-color: #39a7df; }

.sidebar .nav .nav>li { border-left: 0; }

.sidebar .nav .nav>li>a, .sidebar .nav .nav>li>.nav-item { display: block; position: relative; padding: 10px 2px 10px 6px; background-color: transparent !important; font-weight: normal; }

.sidebar .nav .nav>li>a:focus, .sidebar .nav .nav>li>.nav-item:focus, .sidebar .nav .nav>li>a:hover, .sidebar .nav .nav>li>.nav-item:hover { color: #fff; }

.sidebar .nav .nav>li.active>a, .sidebar .nav .nav>li.active>.nav-item { color: #fff; }

.sidebar .nav .nav>li.active>a:after, .sidebar .nav .nav>li.active>.nav-item:after { border-color: #1c75bf; background-color: #1c75bf; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<aside class="aside">
         <div class="nav-primary nav-toggle d-none d-md-inline"> <span class="item-text"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i> </span> </div>
         <nav id="" class="sidebar">
            <ul id="menu-itens" class="nav">
               <li>
                  <a href="javascript: void(0);" data-toggle="collapse-next" class="has-submenu"> <em class="fal fa-address-card"></em><span class="item-text">item</span> </a> 
                  <ul class="nav collapse" aria-expanded="false" style="">
                     <li> <a href="javascript: void(0);" data-toggle="collapse-next" class="has-submenu"> <em class="far fa-boxes"></em><span class="item-text">item</span> </a>  </li>
                     <li> <a href="javascript: void(0);" data-toggle="collapse-next" class="has-submenu"> <em class="fas fa-user-tie"></em><span class="item-text">item</span> </a>  </li>
                     <li> <a href="javascript: void(0);" data-toggle="collapse-next" class="has-submenu"> <em class="far fa-university"></em><span class="item-text">item</span> </a>  </li>
                     <li>
                        <a href="javascript: void(0);" data-toggle="collapse-next" class="has-submenu"> <em class="fal fa-money-bill-alt"></em><span class="item-text">item</span> </a> 
                        <ul class="nav collapse" aria-expanded="false" style="">
                           <li> <a href="#" data-toggle="" class="no-submenu"><span class="item-text">item</span> </a></li>
                           <li> <a href="#" data-toggle="" class="no-submenu"> <span class="item-text">item</span></a></li>
                           <li> <a href="#" data-toggle="" class="no-submenu"> <span class="item-text">item</span></a></li>
                           <li> <a href="#" data-toggle="" class="no-submenu"><span class="item-text">item</span> </a></li>
                           <li> <a href="#" data-toggle="" class="no-submenu"> <span class="item-text">item</span> </a></li>
                           <li> <a href="#" data-toggle="" class="no-submenu"><span class="item-text">item</span> </a></li>
                           <li> <a href="#" data-toggle="" class="no-submenu"> <span class="item-text">item</span> </a></li>
                           <li> <a href="#" data-toggle="" class="no-submenu"><span class="item-text">item</span> </a></li>
                           <li> <a href="#" data-toggle="" class="no-submenu"> <span class="item-text">item</span> </a></li>
                        </ul>
                     </li>
                     <li> <a href="javascript: void(0);" data-toggle="collapse-next" class="has-submenu"> <em class="far fa-object-ungroup"></em><span class="item-text">item</span> </a>  </li>
                     <li> <a href="#" data-toggle="" class="no-submenu"><span class="item-text">item</span> </a></li>
                     <li> <a href="#" data-toggle="" class="no-submenu"><span class="item-text">item</span> </a></li>
                     <li> <a href="#" data-toggle="" class="no-submenu"><span class="item-text">item</span> </a></li>
                     <li> <a href="#" data-toggle="" class="no-submenu"><span class="item-text">item</span> </a></li>
                     <li> <a href="#" data-toggle="" class="no-submenu"><span class="item-text">item</span> </a></li>
                     <li> <a href="#" data-toggle="" class="no-submenu"><span class="item-text">item</span> </a></li>
                  </ul>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <a href="javascript: void(0);" data-toggle="collapse-next" class="has-submenu"> <em class="fal fa-handshake"></em><span class="item-text">item</span> </a> 
                  <ul class="nav collapse show" aria-expanded="false" style="">
                     <li> <a href="javascript: void(0);" data-toggle="collapse-next" class="has-submenu"> <em class="far fa-file-alt"></em><span class="item-text">item</span> </a>  </li>
                     <li>
                        <a href="javascript: void(0);" data-toggle="collapse-next" class="has-submenu"> <em class="far fa-truck"></em><span class="item-text">item</span> </a> 
                        <ul class="nav collapse" aria-expanded="false">
                           <li> <a href="#" data-toggle="" class="no-submenu"> <span class="item-text">item</span> </a></li>
                           <li> <a href="#" data-toggle="" class="no-submenu"> <span class="item-text">item</span> </a></li>
                           <li> <a href="#" data-toggle="" class="no-submenu"> <span class="item-text">item</span> </a></li>
                           <li> <a href="#" data-toggle="" class="no-submenu"> <span class="item-text">item</span> </a></li>
                           <li> <a href="#" data-toggle="" class="no-submenu"> <span class="item-text">item</span></a></li>
                           <li> <a href="#" data-toggle="" class="no-submenu"> <span class="item-text">item</span></a></li>
                        </ul>
                     </li>
                     <li> <a href="javascript: void(0);" data-toggle="collapse-next" class="has-submenu"> <em class="far fa-truck-loading"></em><span class="item-text">item</span> </a>  </li>
                     <li> <a href="javascript: void(0);" data-toggle="collapse-next" class="has-submenu"> <em class="far fa-shopping-cart"></em><span class="item-text">item</span> </a>  </li>
                     <li> <a href="javascript: void(0);" data-toggle="collapse-next" class="has-submenu"> <em class="far fa-clipboard-list"></em><span class="item-text">item</span> </a>  </li>
                     <li> <a href="javascript: void(0);" data-toggle="collapse-next" class="has-submenu"> <em class="far fa-wrench"></em><span class="item-text">item</span> </a>  </li>
                     <li> <a href="javascript: void(0);" data-toggle="collapse-next" class="has-submenu"> <em class="far fa-file-alt"></em><span class="item-text">item</span> </a>  </li>
                     <li>
                        <a href="javascript: void(0);" data-toggle="collapse-next" class="has-submenu">
                           <em class="far fa-shopping-basket"></em><span  
                     </li>
                     <li> <a href="javascript: void(0);" data-toggle="collapse-next" class="has-submenu"> <em class="far fa-dollar-sign"></em><span class="item-text">item</span> </a>  </li> 
                     <li> <a href="javascript: void(0);" data-toggle="collapse-next" class="has-submenu"> <em class="far fa-users"></em><span class="item-text">item</span> </a>  </li>
                     <li>
                        <a href="javascript: void(0);" data-toggle="collapse-next" class="has-submenu">
                           <em class="fal fa-dot-circle"></em><span  
                     </li>
                     <li> <a href="javascript: void(0);" data-toggle="collapse-next" class="has-submenu"> <em class="far fa-clipboard-list"></em><span class="item-text">item</span> </a>  </li> 
                     <li> <a href="javascript: void(0);" data-toggle="collapse-next" class="has-submenu"> <em class="fal fa-dot-circle"></em><span class="item-text">item</span> </a>  </li>
                     <li> <a href="javascript: void(0);" data-toggle="collapse-next" class="has-submenu"> <em class="far fa-box-full"></em><span class="item-text">item</span> </a>  </li>
                     <li>
                        <a href="javascript: void(0);" data-toggle="collapse-next" class="has-submenu">
                           <em class="fal fa-dot-circle"></em><span  
                     </li>
                     <li> <a href="#" data-toggle="" class="no-submenu"><span class="item-text">item</span> </a></li> 
                     <li> <a href="#" data-toggle="" class="no-submenu"><span class="item-text">item</span> </a></li>
                     <li> <a href="#" data-toggle="" class="no-submenu"> <span class="item-text">item</span> </a></li>
                  </ul>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <a href="javascript: void(0);" data-toggle="collapse-next" class="has-submenu"> <em class="far fa-cubes"></em><span class="item-text">item</span> </a> 
                  <ul class="nav collapse" aria-expanded="false" style="">
                     <li> <a href="javascript: void(0);" data-toggle="collapse-next" class="has-submenu"> <em class="far fa-clipboard-list"></em><span class="item-text">item</span> </a>  </li>
                     <li> <a href="javascript: void(0);" data-toggle="collapse-next" class="has-submenu"> <em class="fal fa-dot-circle"></em><span class="item-text">item</span> </a>  </li>
                     <li> <a href="javascript: void(0);" data-toggle="collapse-next" class="has-submenu"> <em class="fal fa-dot-circle"></em><span class="item-text">item</span> </a>  </li>
                     <li> <a href="javascript: void(0);" data-toggle="collapse-next" class="has-submenu"> <em class="far fa-industry-alt"></em><span class="item-text">item</span> </a>  </li>
                     <li> <a href="javascript: void(0);" data-toggle="collapse-next" class="has-submenu"> <em class="far fa-industry-alt"></em><span class="item-text">item</span> </a>  </li>
                     <li> <a href="#" data-toggle="" class="no-submenu"><span class="item-text">item</span> </a></li>
                     <li> <a href="#" data-toggle="" class="no-submenu"><span class="item-text">item</span> </a></li>
                     <li> <a href="#" data-toggle="" class="no-submenu"><span class="item-text">item</span> </a></li>
                     <li> <a href="#" data-toggle="" class="no-submenu"><span class="item-text">item</span> </a></li>
                     <li> <a href="#" data-toggle="" class="no-submenu"><span class="item-text">item</span> </a></li>
                  </ul>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <a href="javascript: void(0);" data-toggle="collapse-next" class="has-submenu"> <em class="fal fa-money-bill-alt"></em><span class="item-text">item</span> </a> 
                  <ul class="nav collapse" aria-expanded="false" style="">
                     <li> <a href="javascript: void(0);" data-toggle="collapse-next" class="has-submenu"> <em class="far fa-dollar-sign"></em><span class="item-text">item</span> </a>  </li>
                     <li> <a href="javascript: void(0);" data-toggle="collapse-next" class="has-submenu"> <em class="far fa-money-check-alt"></em><span class="item-text">item</span> </a>  </li>
                     <li> <a href="javascript: void(0);" data-toggle="collapse-next" class="has-submenu"> <em class="far fa-chart-line"></em><span class="item-text">item</span> </a>  </li>
                     <li> <a href="#" data-toggle="" class="no-submenu"><span class="item-text">item</span> </a></li>
                     <li> <a href="#" data-toggle="" class="no-submenu"><span class="item-text">item</span> </a></li>
                     <li> <a href="#" data-toggle="" class="no-submenu"><span class="item-text">item</span> </a></li>
                     <li> <a href="#" data-toggle="" class="no-submenu"><span class="item-text">item</span> </a></li>
                     <li> <a href="#" data-toggle="" class="no-submenu"><span class="item-text">item</span> </a></li>
                     <li> <a href="#" data-toggle="" class="no-submenu"><span class="item-text">item</span> </a></li>
                     <li> <a href="#" data-toggle="" class="no-submenu"><span class="item-text">item</span> </a></li>
                     <li> <a href="#" data-toggle="" class="no-submenu"><span class="item-text">item</span> </a></li>
                  </ul>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <a href="javascript: void(0);" data-toggle="collapse-next" class="has-submenu"> <em class="fal fa-university"></em><span class="item-text">item</span> </a> 
                  <ul class="nav collapse" aria-expanded="false" style="">
                     <li> <a href="javascript: void(0);" data-toggle="collapse-next" class="has-submenu"> <em class="fal fa-dot-circle"></em><span class="item-text">item</span> </a>  </li>
                     <li> <a href="javascript: void(0);" data-toggle="collapse-next" class="has-submenu"> <em class="fal fa-dot-circle"></em><span class="item-text">item</span> </a>  </li>
                     <li> <a href="javascript: void(0);" data-toggle="collapse-next" class="has-submenu"> <em class="fal fa-dot-circle"></em><span class="item-text">item</span> </a>  </li>
                  </ul>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <a href="javascript: void(0);" data-toggle="collapse-next" class="has-submenu"> <em class="far fa-chart-line"></em><span class="item-text">item</span> </a> 
                  <ul class="nav collapse" aria-expanded="false" style="">
                     <li> <a href="javascript: void(0);" data-toggle="collapse-next" class="has-submenu"> <em class="far fa-clipboard-list"></em><span class="item-text">item</span> </a>  </li>
                     <li> <a href="#" data-toggle="" class="no-submenu"><span class="item-text">item</span> </a></li>
                     <li> <a href="#" data-toggle="" class="no-submenu"><span class="item-text">item</span> </a></li>
                     <li> <a href="#" data-toggle="" class="no-submenu"><span class="item-text">item</span> </a></li>
                     <li> <a href="#" data-toggle="" class="no-submenu"><span class="item-text">item</span> </a></li>
                     <li> <a href="#" data-toggle="" class="no-submenu"><span class="item-text">item</span> </a></li>
                     <li> <a href="#" data-toggle="" class="no-submenu"><span class="item-text">item</span> </a></li>
                     <li> <a href="#" data-toggle="" class="no-submenu"><span class="item-text">item</span> </a></li>
                     <li> <a href="#" data-toggle="" class="no-submenu"><span class="item-text">item</span> </a></li>
                     <li> <a href="#" data-toggle="" class="no-submenu"><span class="item-text">item</span> </a></li>
                     <li> <a href="#" data-toggle="" class="no-submenu"><span class="item-text">item</span> </a></li>
                  </ul>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </nav>
      </aside>
```

Comment: Bom dia, Consegui simular o problema com esse código, reduziu bastante as ocorrências mas ainda acontece. Não gostaria de usar uma solução alternativa como o JQuery, gostaria de usar as funcionalidades padrão do navegador.

Comment: Atualmente para contornar o problema usei um código muito parecido com esse, e está funcionando bem